# Joomla 2.5 content plugin

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm trying to deploy a simple plugin to a Joomla 2.5 installation.  The code in the plugin that is outside the class declaration runs and adds the two script tags to the head.  However, the code within does nothing.  I can't change the $article->title or $article->text.  I've copy and pasted, verbatim from different articles, but everything seems to talk only about 1.5.  The 1.7 stuff that I do find only mentions changing onPrepareContent to onContentPrepare.  Neither seems to do anything.  I would appreciate any help!

```
    <?php
    // No direct access.
    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

    class plgContentPicasaGallery extends JPlugin
    {
        /**
         *
         * @param   string  The context of the content being passed to the plugin.
         * @param   mixed   An object with a "text" property.
         * @param   array   Additional parameters.
         * @param   int     Optional page number. Unused. Defaults to zero.
         * @return  boolean True on success.
         */
        public function onContentBeforeDisplay($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
        {

            if (is_object($article)) {
                $article->text = "omfg, wtf?";
                return true;
            } else {
                $article = "omfg, I'm not an object, wtf?";
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Joomla documentation & tutorials a little bit out dated, new framework changed few things.
To find proper signatures simply look at `/plugins/content/...` files.

Below is proper function signature & phpdoc for `onContentPrepare`.

```
/**
 * @param   string  The context of the content being passed to the plugin.
 * @param   object  The article object.  Note $article->text is also available
 * @param   object  The article params
 * @param   int     The 'page' number
 */
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I updated my code above to something that I took directly from the emailcloak plugin from the /plugins/content/ directory.  I removed everything except the $article->text reference...still doesn't seem to be doing anything to the actual body of the page content.

Comment: did you register and enabled the plugin?

Comment: I did, but I was simply updating the files and what I needed to do was reupload the package, or possibly refresh the cache of the plugin.  Now that I figured that out, I got it working.  Thank you again for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

My noobishness with Joomla prevailed over my good sense.  I was editing the plugin files on the server and I was expecting that to update the plugin.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
$urla= JRequest::getVar('id');
$urlview= JRequest::getVar('view');
if ($urlview=='article')
{}
if ($urla==10<- number id article )
{}
```

i know framework joomla is good but its for understanding method